# How to test path exclusions in Defender

Tags: windows, microsoft-defender

Listing Defender Path exclusions (`(Get-MpPreference).ExclusionPath`), there is quite long list. Some paths contain wildcard and/or environment variables. There might be configured also file extensions exclusions.

Is there a single command (or utility) which would tell whether a specific file or folder is excluded? I mean for purpose of testing the configuration..

The closest I found so far is `MpCmdRun.exe -CheckExclusion -path <path>` but it only checks whether the path is listed in the exclusions, it does not even expand the environment variables..

(I'm on Windows 11)

Answer (score 0):

Only one way I can think of : Find a product that Defender doesn't like
and initiate a scan of the disk or of a parent folder (not a scan of
the folder itself).

One example of a product that I remember Defender disliking are the
[NirSoft tools](https://www.nirsoft.net/).
You could try downloading the
[NirLauncher](https://launcher.nirsoft.net/)
which contains all of them.

Try storing the tools first in a non-excluded folder, to be sure Defender
still doesn't like them.

Comment: Interesting idea, but not exactly what I was looking for :) I was thinking about calculating the excluded paths by expanding variables in context of the current user and checking whether the tested path falls into exclusions..  It must be a step in the Defender logic to decide whether the file/folder should be scanned or not and I hoped  this logic could be called externally for such a test